# How to solve for multiple unknowns using substitution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics

$R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_4$, $R_5$ and $V_6$ suppose to be 'known' values.

$$\frac{V_{n_1}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{n_1}-V_{n_3}}{R_2} + i_6 = 0$$

$$ \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{n_3}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{n_4}}{R_3} - i_6 = 0 $$

$$ \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_1}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_2}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_3}}{R_5} = 0 $$

$$ V_{n_4} = V_6 $$

$$ V_{n_1}-V_{n_2} = 2V_6 $$

I could not see a quick way to solve it using substitution, because if you want to solve for $V_{n_1}$ for example, you have $V_{n_2}$ and $V_{n_3}$ as unknowns. Could anyone help me with this?

Could I do this?:
Substitute  $ V_{n_1} = 2V_6 + V_{n_2} $
in
$\frac{V_{n_1}}{R_1} + \frac{V_{n_1}-V_{n_3}}{R_2} + i_6 = 0$
to get:

$$\frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}}{R_1} + \frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}-V_{n_3}}{R_2} + i_6 = 0$$

And add $ \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{n_3}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{6}}{R_3} - i_6 = 0 $ (after this substitution: $ V_{n_4} = V_6 $) to it to get:

$$\frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}}{R_1} + \frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}-V_{n_3}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{6}}{R_3}+ \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{n_3}}{R_4}  = 0$$

Now I can substitute $ V_{n_1} = 2V_6 + V_{n_2} $ in
$ \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_1}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_2}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_3}}{R_5} = 0 $ to get:

$$ \frac{V_{n_3}-2V_6 - V_{n_2}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_2}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_3}}{R_5} = 0 $$

And add the last two equations to get:

$$ \frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}}{R_1} +  \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{6}}{R_3} +  \frac{V_{n_3}}{R_5} = 0 $$

But now, I still have two unknowns.

$ \frac{V_{n_3}-2V_6 - V_{n_2}}{R_2} + \frac{V_{n_3}-V_{n_2}}{R_4} + \frac{V_{n_3}}{R_5} = 0 $

$ V_{n_3} (\frac{1}{R_5} + \frac{1}{R_4} + \frac{1}{R_2})  = \frac{2V_6}{R_2} + V_{n_2} (\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_4}) $

$ V_{n_3}  = \frac{\frac{2V_6}{R_2} + V_{n_2} (\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_4})}{(\frac{1}{R_5} + \frac{1}{R_4} + \frac{1}{R_2})} $

$ \frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}}{R_1} +  \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{6}}{R_3} +  \frac{\frac{\frac{2V_6}{R_2} + V_{n_2} (\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_4})}{(\frac{1}{R_5} + \frac{1}{R_4} + \frac{1}{R_2})}}{R_5} = 0 $

$ \frac{2V_6 + V_{n_2}}{R_1} +  \frac{V_{n_2}-V_{6}}{R_3} +  \frac{\frac{2V_6}{R_2} + V_{n_2} (\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_4})}{(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{R5}{R_4} + \frac{R5}{R_2})} = 0 $

$ \frac{(1 + \frac{R5}{R_4} + \frac{R5}{R_2})(2V_6 + V_{n_2})}{R_1} +   \frac{(1 + \frac{R5}{R_4} + \frac{R5}{R_2})(V_{n_2}-V_{6})}{R_3} +  \frac{2V_6}{R_2} + V_{n_2} (\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_4}) = 0 $

As you can see, this takes a lot of steps to solve and does not lead to a simple and quick solution....

Comment: Is $V6 = V_{n_6}$?.

Comment: No, $V_6$ is voltage source and therefore it supposed to be 'known'.

Comment: @Huali Do you know what a matrix is?  Have you studied linear algebra at all?

Comment: The "known" value $R_5$ doesn't appear in any of the equations.  Also, is $i_6$ known or unknown?

Comment: @BarryCipra: How stupid of me, I did not add one equation....

Comment: @Huali, it happens.  I'm glad I could help.  I take it this means that $i_6$ is unknown (along with $V_{n_i}$ for $i=1,2,3,4$).

Comment: @BarryCipra I suppose to get 5 equations with 5 unknowns, so I think this $i_6$ is my fifth unknown. But I updated the question and could not solve it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplifly the notation putting, kor $k=1,\ldots, 6$, $V_{n_k}=V_k$, $\frac{1}{R_k}=G_k$, $i_6=i$ and $V_6=v$.
In this way, your system becomes
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
V_1G_1+(V_1-V_3)G_2&=-i\\
(V_2-V_3)G_4+(V_2-V_4)G_3&=i\\
(V_3-V_1)G_2+(V_3-V_2)G_4+V_3G_5&=0\\
V_4&=v\\
V_1-V_2&=2v
\end{align}\right.
$$
or
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
(G_1+G2)V_1-G_2V_3+i&=0  & (E_1)\\
(G_3+G_4)V_2-G_4V_3-G_3V_4-i&=0 & (E_2)\\
-G_2V_1-G_4V_2+(G_2+G_4+G_5)V_3&=0 & (E_3)\\
V_4&=v & (E_4)\\
V_1-V_2&=2v & (E_5)
\end{align}\right.
$$
So you have five equation in the five unkwnown $V_1,V_2,V_3, V_4, i$.

Now follow these steps:

1. $E_1+E_2+G_3E_4\to E_2$: substitute the second equation with the sum  of the first and the second equation and the third multiplied by $G_3$;
2. $E_2+E_3\to E_3$: substitute the third equation with the sum  of the second and the third equation;
3. $\frac{1}{G_5}E_3\to E_3$: substitute the third equation with the third equation divided by $G_5$;
4. $E_5\leftrightarrow E_1$: exchange the first equation and the fifth equation;
5. $(G_2+G_4)E_3+E_2\to E_2$: substitute the second equation with the sum  of the  second equation and the third multiplied by $G_2+G_4$;
6. $-E_1\leftrightarrow E_2$: exchange the second equation and the first equation multiplied by $-1$;
7. $[(G_2+G_4)G_3/G_5+(G_3+G_4)]E_2-E_1\to E_1$: substitute the first equation with the difference of the  second equation multiplied by $(G_2+G_4)G_3/G_5+(G_3+G_4)$ and the first equation.

After the above steps the system becomes
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
g_{11}V_1&=gv  & (E_1)\\
V_2-V_1&=-2v & (E_2)\\
\frac{G_1}{G_5}V_1+\frac{G_3}{G_5}V_2+V_3&=\frac{G_3}{G_5}v & (E_3)\\
V_4&=v & (E_4)\\
(G_1+G_2)V_1-G_2V_3+i&=0 & (E_5)
\end{align}\right.
$$
where 
$$\begin{align}
g_{11}&=(G_2+G_4)\frac{G_1+G_3}{G_5}+G_1+G_2+G_3+G_4\\
g&=2\left[(G_2+G_4)\frac{G_3}{G_5}+G_3+G_4\right]+G_3+(G_3+G_4)\frac{G_3}{G_5}
\end{align}
$$
Finally we will find
$$\small
\left\{
\begin{align}
V_1&=v\frac{g}{g_{11}}\\
V_2&=V_1-2v=v\left(\frac{g}{g_{11}}-2\right)\\
V_3&=\frac{G_3}{G_5}v-\frac{G_1}{G_5}V_1-\frac{G_3}{G_5}V_2=v\left[\frac{G_3}{G_5}-\frac{G_1}{G_5}\frac{g}{g_{11}}-\frac{G_3}{G_5}\left(\frac{g}{g_{11}}-2\right)\right]\\
V_4&=v\\
i&=-(G_1+G_2)V_1+G_2V_3=v\left\{-(G_1+G_2)\frac{g}{g_{11}}+G_2\left[\frac{G_3}{G_5}-\frac{G_1}{G_5}\frac{g}{g_{11}}-\frac{G_3}{G_5}\left(\frac{g}{g_{11}}-2\right)\right]\right\}
\end{align}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third equation to eliminate $V_{n_4}$  The second gives $V_{n_1}=2V_6+V_{n_2}$. Use that to eliminate $V_{n_1}$ from the first two, which leaves two equations in two unknowns.  In general, you just use one equation to eliminate one unknown from the rest and continue until you are down to one equation in one unknown.  If $i_6$ is not already known, you are one equation short as you have five unknowns.

Comment: I see I made a mistake, I added the equation now. There are now 5 equations and 5 unknowns?

Comment: I updated the question, Could you see which mistake I made?

Comment: Not a mistake, but you can add the first two to get rid of $i_6$.  When you solve for a variable, you replace it in all the rest of the equations.  Each step of that gets rid of one variable and one equation.  You can get rid of $V_{n_4}$ directly.  Then when you write $V_{n_1} = 2V_6 + V_{n_2}$ you should replace $V_{n_1}$ in all the equations.  Basically you want the shortest route to a single equation in one unknown.